# Call to a member function fetchOne() on a non-object in ../Observer.php on line 25

Tags: php, magento

below is my code

```
 $result = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')
 ->getConnection('core_read')
 ->fetchOne("SHOW TABLES LIKE 'dog_config'"); // error comes in this function
```

Can anyone help in resolving this.
     Thanks in advance

Comment: `getConnection('core_read')` probably returns false. You should check logs what happened

Comment: yes i checked but no log created for this issue

Comment: I tried your code it is working fine, check your connection object, there seems to be a issue in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write your query as below:-

```
$connection = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_read');
$sql        = "Your_SQL_Query"; // write your sql query here
$result     = $connection->fetchOne($sql); // You can use fetchRow($sql), fetchAll($sql) as per your need.
```

**Note**:- If still getting error then print `$connection` before `$rows`.

Check this [link](http://fishpig.co.uk/magento/tutorials/direct-sql-queries/) also.